# ERROR using a class as a vector type - "Undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++

**Hello Stack Overflow!**

I have encountered a problem which I have tried to solve but have not succeeded with, therefore I am turning my head towards you programmers hoping for answers.

What I am suspecting the problem is, is that it has to do with my **main.cpp** which I haven't started coding in yet for reasons. Could be very wrong though.

Any tips/hints are appreciated!

The error is about this part located in the BankFunctions header

```
// Vector
   static std::vector<accounts> users;
```

The error messages are listed at the bottom.

I have included the two class header files.

---

**Main.cpp:**

```
// Classes
#include "BankFunctions.h" // Handles the bank functions
#include "accounts.h" // Handles the customer accounts

// Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Class 1: Accounts**

Header:

```
#pragma once

// Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

// Classes
#include "BankFunctions.h"

class accounts
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        accounts(
            unsigned int newId, 
            unsigned int newAge, 
            unsigned int newSSN, 
            std::string newFirstName,
            std::string newLastName, 
            std::string newAdress, 
            std::string newEmail, 
            double newBalance
        );

        // Overload constructor
        accounts(std::string eId, std::string eNAge, std::string eSSN, std::string eFName, std::string eLName, std::string eEmail, std::string eAdress, std::string eNBalance);

        // Mutators
        inline void setId(unsigned int i) { id = i; }
        inline void setAge(unsigned int a) { age = a; }
        inline void setSSN(unsigned int ssn) { SSN = ssn; }
        inline void setFirstName(std::string FN) { firstName = FN; }
        inline void setLastName(std::string LN) { lastName = LN; }
        inline void setEmail(std::string em) { email = em; }
        inline void setAdress(std::string adr) { adress = adr; }
        inline void setBalance(double newBalance, bool t);

        // Accessors
        inline unsigned int getId() const { return id; }
        inline unsigned int getAge() const { return age; }
        inline unsigned int getSSN() const { return SSN; }
        inline std::string getFirstName() const { return firstName; }
        inline std::string getLastName() const { return lastName; }
        inline std::string getEmail() const { return email; }
        inline std::string getAdress() const { return adress; }
        inline double getBalance() const { return balance; }

    private:
        // Customer account details
        unsigned int id;
        unsigned int age;
        unsigned int SSN; // Social Security Number
        std::string firstName;
        std::string lastName;
        std::string adress;
        std::string email;
        double balance;
};
```

---

**Class 2: BankFunctions**

Header:

```
#pragma once

// Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

// Classes
#include "accounts.h"

class BankFunctions
{
    public:
        BankFunctions();
        static void loadVector(); // Loads in customer account information into objects that get stored into a vector. (All the existing accounts get loaded in)
        static void newCustomer(); // Create new customer account
        static void existingCustomer(); // View customer account
        static void deposit(unsigned int accId); // Deposit money function
        static void withdraw(unsigned int accId); // Withdraw money function

        // Edit customer account
        static void editCustomerDetails(unsigned int accId);
            // Related Functions
            static void editAge(unsigned int accId);
            static void editSSN(unsigned int accId);
            static void editFirstName(unsigned int accId);
            static void editLastName(unsigned int accId);
            static void editAdress(unsigned int accId);
            static void editEmail(unsigned int accId);
            static void editBalance(unsigned int accId);

    private:
        // Vector
        static std::vector<accounts> users;

        static unsigned int amountOfAccounts;

};
```

---

**ERROR Message:**

```
...bankfunctions.h(36): error C2065: 'accounts': undeclared identifier
...bankfunctions.h(36): error C2923: 'std::vector': 'accounts' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
...bankfunctions.h(36): error C3203: 'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: `BankFunctions` shouldn't be a class. And why does `accounts.h` include `BankFunctions.h`?

Comment: @melpomene The reason as to why I chose to make it into a class was because I am currently experimenting and learning about classes so I wanted to use classes as much as I can. Now afterwards I kinda see how it's not really suited to be a class, but hey, it's done.



And for the include, I am not sure myself. I think I was experimenting earlier and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Unrelated: Good on you for stopping and testing before trying to write the program logic. This is exactly the right time to ask this question.

Comment: @melpomene That include in the accounts.h was the problem afterall!

Comment: Take the time to read the link posted by melpomene ([Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)) because it explains exactly what happens to cause this problem in detail. Knowing the what and why can keep you from falling into similar traps later.

Comment: @user4581301 Will defo do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just to remove the `include BankFunctions.h` from the accounts.h.

The problem, I think, is that an include performs simply an inserting of the whole header file at the position where the include is done, but `pragma once` ensures that you do not include a header twice into a cpp file.
When your headers include each other it is possible to get the class definition of `accounts` past the line 36 of BankFunctions.h where you need it.

You may also put an extra `class accounts;` on the very top of main.cpp. This should also work, but is not a pretty solution.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!